# Android check WIFI status (disconnected or user changed WIFI)

Tags: java, android, service, connection, wifi

I is there a way to Flag if a WIFI connection got disconnected/ dropped off OR if the user actually changed the WIFI network ?

I need my app to do :
Connect to a WIFI XYZ, if XYZ get disconnect (FLAG 1) or dropped off Then reconnect to XYZ.
But is the user change to another wifi BTOpen (FLAG 2) then allow the connect and Stop my service.
If user connect to XYZ again then start the loop again.

What I got so far is :

```
    <!-- WIFI Receiver -->
    <receiver android:name=".ReceiverWifi" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".ServiceWifiMonitor" />
    <receiver android:name=".ServiceController" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action   android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
    myApplication = (MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
    conManager  = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    networkInfo = conManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);


    boolean isConnected = networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
    int reconnectedCount = myApplication.getReconnectedCount();


    if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {


        if("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE".equals(intent.getAction())) {


            //Start and Stop Service
            if(myApplication.isReconnect()) startServiceWifiMonitor(); else stopServiceWifiMonitor();



            if (isConnected) {
                //There is a WIFI Connection
                myApplication.setConnectedWifi(NetworkUtil.getCurrentSSID(context));
                myApplication.setWifiStatus("connected");




                if (NetworkUtil.isConnectedToXYZ(context)) {
                    startServiceWifiMonitor();

                    if(pref.getisFirstTime()) 
                    {
                        myApplication.setWifiByChoise("XYZ");
                        pref.setisFirstTime(false);
                    }
                    else { myApplication.setisReconnect(true); }
                }
                else {
                    //Connected to different NetWork
                    if(myApplication.isReconnect() && NetworkUtil.isXYZAvailable(context)) 
                    {
                        //ReConnect to XYZ
                        NetworkUtil.connectToXYZ(context);
                        myApplication.setReconnectedCount(reconnectedCount++);
                    }
                    else { resetValues("AAAA"); }
                }


            }//end if
            else 
             {
                if(NetworkUtil.isXYZAvailable(context) && myApplication.getWifiByChoise().equals("XYZ")) 
                {
                    NetworkUtil.connectToXYZ(context);
                    myApplication.setReconnectedCount(reconnectedCount++);
                }
                else { resetValues(""); }
            }
        }//end CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
```

Service Monitor:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand > Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);

        objHandler.postDelayed(mTasks, 1000);

    return START_STICKY;
}//end onStartCommand



private Runnable mTasks = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        if(myApplication.getWifiByChoise().equals("XYZ") && NetworkUtil.isXYZAvailable(context)) {              
            try
             {
                //Get the numbers of Reconnection
                int count = myApplication.getReconnectedCount();

                if(!NetworkUtil.isWifiConnected(context)) 
                {   

                    NetworkUtil.connectToXYZ(context);
                    myApplication.setisReconnect(true);
                    myApplication.setReconnectedCount(count++); 
                }

                if(!NetworkUtil.isConnectedToXYZ(context)) 
                {   

                    NetworkUtil.connectToXYZ(context);
                    myApplication.setisReconnect(true);
                    myApplication.setReconnectedCount(count++);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
        else { stopSelf(); }
        int ms_interval = 3000;
        objHandler.postDelayed(mTasks, ms_interval);
    }
};//end Runnable mTasks
```

The problem with my app is that :
It crashed the device, Seems like its eating up all the memory ram.
sometimes with the wifi XYZ get disconnect  it wont connect again and if user change to another wifi, it won't allow the connection.

I really appreciate your help. Thank you.